# Не до конца выполняется BackgroundWorker. C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Есть `BackgroundWorker` который выполняет некий код. После окончания работы, он должен написать переменную в `label`. Но это не происходит. Тогда я решил разбить код в `BackgroundWorker` на маленькие кусочки, после выполнения кусочка кода выводится число кусочка (`Console.WriteLine`), их всего 8. Первый семь - это проверка условий, последний - вывод. То когда я скомпилировал программу, то в выводе увидел:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

C чем это связано?

Код воркера:

```
private void RegistryChecker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int CanOptimisated = 0;

            var printers = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RemoteComputer\NameSpace\{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}");
            //var onedrive = Registry.LocalMachine;
            string unloaddlls = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer";
            string superfetch = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters";
            string prioritycontrol = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl";
            string disableexecuting = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management";
            string enablesmartscreen = @"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System";

            Console.WriteLine(1);
            try
            {
                printers.GetValue("");
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox1.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }
            catch
            {
                guna2CheckBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox1.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(2);
            if (CheckRegistry(unloaddlls, "AlwaysUnloadDll", "1") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox2.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox2.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(3);
            if (CheckRegistry(superfetch, "EnableSuperfetch", "0") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox4.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox4.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox4.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox4.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(4);
            if (CheckRegistry(superfetch, "EnablePrefetcher", "0") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox5.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox5.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox5.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox5.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(5);
            if (CheckRegistry(prioritycontrol, "Win32PrioritySeparation", "6") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox6.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox6.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox6.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox6.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(6);
            if (CheckRegistry(disableexecuting, "DisablePagingExecutive", "1") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox7.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox7.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox7.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox7.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(7);
            if (CheckRegistry(enablesmartscreen, "EnableSmartScreen", "0") == true)
            {
                guna2CheckBox8.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox8.Enabled = false;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                CanOptimisated++;
                guna2CheckBox8.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    guna2CheckBox8.Enabled = true;
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(8);

            label9.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                label9.Text = CanOptimisated + " Пунктов";
            }));

        }

        bool CheckRegistry(string path, string nameValue, string value)
        {
            var path1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);

            if (path1.GetValue(nameValue).ToString() == value)
            {
                path1.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                path1.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Метод, который запускает воркера:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            guna2GradientCircleButton2.PerformClick();
            RegistryChecker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Объект CanOptimisated какого типа? Вы дожидаетесь окончания работы BackgroundWorker в основной программе? А то может она у вас раньше заканчивается. В общем, посмотреть бы больше кода.

Comment: Еще `BackgroundWorker` очень старый, и использовать его неудобно. С очень большой вероятностью ваш код можно написать проще, но вы его не показали. Покажите весь метод, где воркер запускается и весь его обработчик целиком. А так, ваша проблема за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: int CanOptimisated

Comment: Покажите код метода, который запускает воркера.

Comment: Добавил, можете смотреть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее вероятно, что внутри воркера у вас возникает исключение, которое вы не отлавливаете, но так как оно выполняется в не основном потоке, и этим основным потоком никак не ожидается, то возникшее исключение проваливается в бездну, вы просто его не видите.

Избежать этого можно используя более современный подход к параллельным вычислениям и асинхронным операциям.

```cs
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<Action> callback = new Progress<Action>(action => action()); // заменитель инвока
    try
    {
        guna2GradientCircleButton2.PerformClick();
        await Task.Run(() => RegistryChecker(callback));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void RegistryChecker(IProgress<Action> status)
{
    int CanOptimisated = 0;
    //var onedrive = Registry.LocalMachine;

    const string printerspath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RemoteComputer\NameSpace\{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}";
    const string unloaddlls = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer";
    const string superfetch = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters";
    const string prioritycontrol = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl";
    const string disableexecuting = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management";
    const string enablesmartscreen = @"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System";

    Debug.WriteLine(1); // используйте вместо Console в GUI приложениях
    bool check1 = false;
    try
    {
        // RegistryKey - IDisposable, с ним можно вот так.
        using (RegistryKey printers = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(printerspath))
        {
            printers.GetValue("");
        }
        CanOptimisated++;
        check1 = true;
    }
    catch { }
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox1.Enabled = check1); // было 15 инвоков, стало 8

    Debug.WriteLine(2);
    bool check2 = !CheckRegistry(unloaddlls, "AlwaysUnloadDll", "1");
    if (check2)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox2.Enabled = check2);

    Debug.WriteLine(3);
    bool check4 = !CheckRegistry(superfetch, "EnableSuperfetch", "0");
    if (check4)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox4.Enabled = check4);

    Debug.WriteLine(4);
    bool check5 = !CheckRegistry(superfetch, "EnablePrefetcher", "0");
    if (check5)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox5.Enabled = check5);

    Debug.WriteLine(5);
    bool check6 = !CheckRegistry(prioritycontrol, "Win32PrioritySeparation", "6");
    if (check6)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox6.Enabled = check6);

    Debug.WriteLine(6);
    bool check7 = !CheckRegistry(disableexecuting, "DisablePagingExecutive", "1");
    if (check7)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox7.Enabled = check7);

    Debug.WriteLine(7);
    bool check8 = !CheckRegistry(enablesmartscreen, "EnableSmartScreen", "0");
    if (check8)
        CanOptimisated++;
    status.Report(() => guna2CheckBox8.Enabled = check8);

    Debug.WriteLine(8);
    status.Report(() => label9.Text = CanOptimisated + " Пунктов");
}

private bool CheckRegistry(string path, string nameValue, string value)
{
    // этот метод тоже немного упростился
    using (RegistryKey path1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path))
    {
        return path1.GetValue(nameValue).ToString() == value;
    }
}
```

Проверьте этот код, он должен либо точно отработать, либо точно вернуть ошибку. Эту стену повторяющегося кода можно еще упростить, засунув в цикл, но я не стал изменять ваш код до неузнаваемости, а просто сократил.

Как вы уже поняли, `BackgroundWorker` больше не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо. Возвращает ошибку.

Comment: @mounten1 теперь отладка вас спасет :)

Comment: @mounten1 кстати, если реестр будет творить чудеса (типа какой-нибудь ключ есть, но приложение его не видит), попробуйте изменить архитектуру сборки приложения с Any CPU на x64.